# Why does God devastate Israel's vines and fig trees and not other crops in Hosea 2:12?

Tags: cultural-analysis, hosea

In Hosea 2:12 it says

> “I will destroy her vines and fig trees,
>
> Of which she said, ‘These are my wages Which my lovers have given me.’
>
> And I will make them a forest, And the beasts of the field will devour them. - NASB

and

> I will devastate her vines and fig trees.
>
> She thinks that these are her wages that her lovers have given her.
>
> I will turn them into a thicket, and the wild animals will eat them. - HCSB

**Why does Israel say that the vines and figs are her wages? Wouldn't the nation have other crops to rely on besides just wine and figs, especially considering that v. 9 mentions that Yahweh will take back his grain in its time?** I understand this is God's punishment for the promiscuity of the nation, but I don't see how it's any more effective than let's say *taking away a child's TV privileges by sending them to their room where all their other toys are*. Forgive me for the crude analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why does God devastate Israel's vines and fig trees and not other crops in Hosea 2:12**

From the scriptures we note that figs and raisins were a staple food , the figs were pressed into cakes, which were handy for carrying,  for example Abigail send David 200 cakes of pressed figs, and 100 cakes of pressed raisins.

1 Samuel 25:18  (NABRE)

> 18 "Abigail quickly got together two hundred loaves, two skins of
>   wine, five dressed sheep, five seahs of roasted grain, **a hundred cakes
>   of pressed raisins, and two hundred cakes of pressed figs,** and loaded
>   them on donkeys."

1 Samuel 30:12 (NABRE)

> 12 "They also offered a cake of pressed figs and two cakes of pressed
>   raisins. When he had eaten, he revived, for he had not taken food nor
>   drunk water for three days and three nights."

1 Chronicles 12:40  (NRSV)

> 40 "And also their neighbors, from as far away as Issachar and Zebulun
>   and Naphtali, came bringing food on donkeys, camels, mules, and
>   oxen—abundant provisions of meal, cakes of figs, clusters of raisins,
>   wine, oil, oxen, and sheep, for there was joy in Israel."

Apparently ,figs were usually planted in vine yards:

Luke 13:6  (NRSV)

The Parable of the Barren Fig Tree

> 6 "Then he told this parable: “A man had a fig tree planted in his
>   vineyard; and he came looking for fruit on it and found none."

2 Kings 18:31  (NRSV)

> 31" Do not listen to Hezekiah; for thus says the king of Assyria:
>   ‘Make your peace with me and come out to me; then every one of you
>   will eat from your own vine and your own fig tree, and drink water
>   from your own cistern."

Joel 2:22  (NRSV)

> 22 "Do not fear, you animals of the field, for the pastures of the
>   wilderness are green; the tree bears its fruit, the fig tree and vine
>   give their full yield."

Due to the importance of the figs and raisins, being a common food  in the nations supply ,its failure would have disastrous effects on the chain supply . Like Hosea 2:12, when  destruction was foretold on the  land , the fig trees received a mentioned . Jeremiah 8:13,Habakkuk 3:17.  Joel wrote:

Joel 1:7  (NRSV)

> 7" It has laid waste my vines,  and splintered my fig trees; it has
>   stripped off their bark and thrown it down, their branches have turned
>   white."